# What are the alternatives to MozyPro for server-level file system off site backups?

Tags: backup, cloud-storage

Due to problems with getting support, we are currently looking to move away from using MozyPro to backup our Windows servers (150 GB~ of file shares and various development tools for our team of programmers).

We use MozyPro specifically for off-site backups. We have an additional on-site backup solution in place, that is run entirely local.

We are looking for good alternatives to using MozyPro for off-site backup, considering:

- We have plenty of upload bandwidth
- We need to backup about 175 GB of data
- It needs to have a client for Windows server 2003/8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Rackspace, a partner of Iron Mountain (hello @mfinni!).  However, I was a customer long before I became an employee, and I don't work for the part of the business that makes our backup product.

We offer a product called [JungleDisk Server Edition](https://www.jungledisk.com/business/server/features/) that does server backup to Rackspace Cloud Files or S3.  Prices are $5 per server per month for the software license and $0.15 per GB per month for storage.  First 10GB are free on each server and there are no data transfer charges for Cloud Files.

This is for file-level backup, not system state.  It doesn't have quite as many features as a LiveVault-type service but is much cheaper.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because we have been happily using JDSE for some time now.

Comment: I use JDSE on a number of both Linux and Windows servers and have been very happy with it for the past year.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer : I work for Iron Mountain, and my opinions expressed here are my own. I don't work for the Iron Mountain Digital, the division that makes these products.

We have a product called [LiveVault](http://www.ironmountain.com/online-backup/server/server-backup.html) that does online server backup. If you're running backup software from our partners (I'm aware of MS DPM and Commvault), you can also do your existing backups to our cloud without replacing/adding to your existing software. That's two potential solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend Azure Backup, as it has a number of advanced features (like multi-region data replication, and a very powerful backup agent).

In our case, we were not able to use it because it requires active directory.

Details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/trial/get-started-backup/